# C++ performance std::array vs std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking, stdvector, stdarray

I know C-style arrays or `std::array` aren't faster than vectors. I use vectors all the time (and I use them well). However, I have some situation in which the use of `std::array` performs better than with `std::vector`, and I have no clue why (tested with clang 7.0 and gcc 8.2).

Let me share a simple code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

// some size constant
const size_t N = 100;

// some vectors and arrays
using vec = std::vector<double>;
using arr = std::array<double,3>;
// arrays are constructed faster here due to known size, but it is irrelevant
const vec v1 {1.0,-1.0,1.0};
const vec v2 {1.0,2.0,1.0};
const arr a1 {1.0,-1.0,1.0};
const arr a2 {1.0,2.0,1.0};

// vector to store combinations of vectors or arrays
std::vector<double> glob(N,0.0);
```

The above code which initializes the variables is not included in the benchmark. Now, let's write a function to combine elements (`double`) of `v1` and `v2`, or of `a1` and `a2`:

```
// some combination
auto comb(const double m, const double f)
{
  return m + f;
}
```

And the benchmark functions:

```
void assemble_vec()
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<N-2; ++i)
    {
        glob[i] += comb(v1[0],v2[0]);
        glob[i+1] += comb(v1[1],v2[1]);
        glob[i+2] += comb(v1[2],v2[2]);
    }  
}

void assemble_arr()
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<N-2; ++i)
    {
        glob[i] += comb(a1[0],a2[0]);
        glob[i+1] += comb(a1[1],a2[1]);
        glob[i+2] += comb(a1[2],a2[2]);
    }  
}
```

I've tried this with clang 7.0 and gcc 8.2. In both cases, the array version goes almost twice as fast as the vector version.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?  Also, 100 is a very small number of test cases.  Normally you want at least tens of thousands of iterations when benchmarking.  You can use [quick bench](http://quick-bench.com/) for a online benchmarker.

Comment: Do you have some optimization flags enabled? One possibility is that the compiler does some intrinsic magic behind the scene.

Comment: ...moreover your test are rather susceptible to compiler optimizations, only one of the assignments inside the loop will have an obersvable effect. I would try to minize such opportunites for the compiler to optimize when measuring and comparing runtimes

Comment: Arrays and vectors solve different problems. I don't really see a purpose in comparing their performances in this way.

Comment: *I know C-style arrays or std::array aren't faster than vectors.* This is not a base assumption I would start with as a programmer, since stack-allocated memory is generally presumed to be faster than dynamic memory.

Comment: @Xirema I've heard that *allocating* dynamic memory slow compared to "allocating" stack memory. But I haven't heard that stack memory is faster than dynamically allocated memory. Is this a cache hit thing?

Comment: @Xirema you might have a point there!

Comment: @NathanOliver N=100 doesn't have anything to do with the benchmark, it's just the size of the vector which holds the combinations. I'll edit the question to make that clear, thanks. Optimization flag O3 (@Gilad). I ran the benchmark on the webpage quick benchmarks

Comment: The reason of the difference is that `a1` and `a2` are const. The compiler calculates their sum compile-time. Unfortunately, gcc and clang is not clever enough to move `comb(v1[0], v2[0])` out of the loop (not even if their `data()` is put into a `__restrict` pointer - that's a missed optimization).

Comment: @geza I don't understand your comment. Indeed, the performance is the same when removing the consts. Could you please post a full answer? Thanks!

Comment: Vector should be slower than array, since it has one more level of indirection, and it has to check sizes almost all the time whereas everything is static in an array

Comment: @phuclv: ISO C++ does *not* require bounds checks on `std::vector::operator[]`, only for [`std::vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).  Type-based aliasing lets the compiler hoist the level of indirection out of the loop, only loading pointers once before the loop.  (Because storing a `double` can be assumed not to modify the `double*` members of `glob`.)

Comment: @MFnx: The compiler could do the same optimization, if it realized that `v1` and `v2` are const as well. Or, it could do an optimization, if it realized, that `v1` and `v2` doesn't overlap with `glob`. So, it could precompute their sum before the loop. But it doesn't realize it. If I try to help it, with getting vector's internal data pointer into a local `__restrict` pointer variable (basically `__restrict` tells the compiler that the pointer doesn't overlap with anything) doesn't help either. That's a missing optimization from the compilers' part.

Comment: @geza Ok, I understand! So, the answer of Xirema would not be accurate?

Comment: @MFnx: it misses the key part, that why do the two versions compiled differently, and the array version has compile-time summation of `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: I don't like people editing my question by removing "Good evening"....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**C++ aliasing rules don't let the compiler prove that `glob[i] += stuff` doesn't modify one of the elements of `const vec v1 {1.0,-1.0,1.0};` or `v2`.**

`const` on a `std::vector` means the "control block" pointers can be assumed to not be modified after it's constructed, but the memory is still dynamically allocated an all the compiler knows is that it effectively has a `const double *` in static storage.

Nothing in the `std::vector` implementation lets the compiler rule out some *other* `non-const` pointer pointing into that storage.  For example, the `double *data` in the control block of `glob`.

**C++ doesn't provide a way for library implementers to give the compiler the information that the storage for different `std::vector`s doesn't overlap.**  They can't use `__restrict` (even on compilers that support that extension) because that could break programs that take the address of a vector element.  See [the C99 documentation for `restrict`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict).

---

But with `const arr a1 {1.0,-1.0,1.0};` and `a2`, the doubles themselves can go in read-only static storage, and the compiler knows this.  **Therefore it can evaluate `comb(a1[0],a2[0]);` and so on *at compile time***.  In @Xirema's answer, you can see the asm output loads constants `.LC1` and `.LC2`.  (Only two constants because both `a1[0]+a2[0]` and `a1[2]+a2[2]` are `1.0+1.0`.  The loop body uses `xmm2` as a source operand for `addsd` twice, and the other constant once.)

---

#### But couldn't the compiler still do the sums once outside the loop at runtime?

No, again because of potential aliasing.  It doesn't know that stores into `glob[i+0..3]` won't modify the contents of `v1[0..2]`, so it reloads from v1 and v2 every time through the loop after the store into `glob`.

(It doesn't have to reload the `vector<>` control block pointers, though, because type-based strict aliasing rules let it assume that storing a `double` doesn't modify a `double*`.)

The compiler *could* have checked that `glob.data() + 0 .. N-3` didn't overlap with either of `v1/v1.data() + 0 .. 2`, and made a different version of the loop for that case, hoisting the three `comb()` results out of the loop.

**This is a useful optimization that some compilers do when auto-vectorizing if they can't prove lack of aliasing**; it's clearly a missed optimization in your case that gcc doesn't check for overlap because it would make the function run much faster.  But the question is whether the compiler could reasonably guess that it was worth emitting asm that checks at runtime for overlap, and has 2 different versions of the same loop.  With profile-guided optimization, it would know the loop is hot (runs many iterations), and would be worth spending extra time on.  But without that, the compiler might not want to risk bloating the code too much.

ICC19 (Intel's compiler) in fact *does* do something like that here, but it's weird: if you look at the beginning of `assemble_vec` ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByHQGY8tZK1NYA1FtsBhAG6ZkRYg9sLQkAQTsHJxdMdy9mYmJmAE8gkPCwgHoM1xMAWxijPAAvGLRaIwJ1AjSyipzizAB9AlcAOViAEVdOCQkPfTC0rJzUfNdffxIjV3V0GYTkozTTQo1xv06cgnQQEAmAj090MwAjdlTbAdCVh2B54k2KnZB4xJSvY9MzzFJbC6vhq9FvNSnQKsRTP5MHMqMwKpgHggETF0KYYkRXABrWioADutHqJVIrhOphahFceGmeASmHY3iqNTBLQm4047mkuh4ElIAFpuaRuVppB1%2BkzyiyNt5eByudwebx5YL5cLRZdxXVXjN2cK5Tz%2BUqhSKxWFai0tcwZbqBYqeUa1Vchtl9iRXBiKiRQbkTg5mAQ8GDXKgqOtJsRpq6gUklmEnrsXYEPqdzrZsK5gKxUCcIK1SBJ5QBKE3pULDPJen20P0B2hpZhk1CuNDeiBm1yfb6uXLEtsd9iuKhFwactKuVzETAEcwE3LuPQD4uqtJpRqNP0EYh4UkEJqNKA4hysByYAtD0LeVB4OZwoyYb3sRoTCBn3WjscD10QQolZqUjwdPpLj/LxWl5Xh%2BjnfQ9DwM931lN84LHDMsy0MRdDwVCugMf8m1GbNvE4VDdD6MQOlIaUiJIjoi3VMJEPfZCTiIjC9EI0jIJw5t8LYrlMPI8C0LY6ji3opDMyYtCWN0ASsL0Ti8IgAiiJk/jlMwmirjg1Ux2XY1BjCVd103bdd33S9aCPWgTzPC8rxmIxb3vJpXmfXTNPfGgHi/Bpfww2wAIgvzPFA8CgOw6DYPfV86NExjmMwjj/NwltmB4qjSEtSj1JE2LxPi1iEuwpKuIgVKiKEjKBN40iNIQxC4skgwZMSroSrKtCVMyjrsto0ItJFHTh1FfTQgcFpcmYBxn3gmKxxvO9vkfPxXN6uCJynYgCQarleD%2BUjFz00IrALVQQCsMQrFIWgzokS7UDOzxwt0EZzEsOdbE4S6CBu46TsxEBJFOqwREu66rFu0h7qsS6jBAHlvvB47SDgWAYEQFBRgABzwdgyAoVssZxhEQGAfheFIKgcZ3cNKBOH7SEreIkjOz7SGbfJ6AAeQs5nEdILAJo0dh6fwCd/DwXxYb5zAAA8/DJaxWbGul6aPE5EmIJJPAwRWvs3XIWaRmh6CYNgOB4ARhHEKRZHkBQ1A0FAntULdYcgE7UEx/0wTO3kAHU2FYVxeU52xg6ef9gFoUwns4aQYbMCxzZO1gzouq76ahmX%2BAANl5HORHTZBkFcfg%2BFcCBcEIV07E4YltdybHcfezgC1cR65L0L6ftPUh/sB1Pgcug3AbBiGoZhuHSAR26TpR9HmybhFyEoReieIEA8GLzhBDrynWGp2GIDpvnGc1w22dGDmCG51heYhgX1AzawH5pPx/Ul%2BnZflncL%2BVweIZqw1lrHWF8Nx4ANlYT6J1jaMBYMLC2QhRCSBkHbe2T8nad0MGrN2z5IZexrFLf2gdg6h3DtsSO0dY7x2MInSwXAU5p1BpnM62c84F0pMXbogh5TcHZJXfAAQW710Js3OwvA24dygrobuiNe5ImYFgDeeDB4g1ICPHkY87pnUnvDHuf0AY8kHrYZhfMJ7T30UDXgpjx46IsXIk6vhww1hACIIAA%3D%3D)), it load the data pointer from `glob`, then adds 8 and subtracts the pointer again, producing a constant `8`.  Then it branches at runtime on `8 > 784` (not taken) and then `-8 < 784` (taken).  It looks like this was supposed to be an overlap check, but it maybe used the same pointer twice instead of v1 and v2?  (`784 = 8*100 - 16 = sizeof(double)*N - 16`)

Anyway, it ends up running the `..B2.19` loop that hoists all 3 `comb()` calculations, and interestingly does 2 iterations at once of the loop with 4 scalar loads and stores to `glob[i+0..4]`, and 6 `addsd` (scalar double) add instructions.

Elsewhere in the function body, there's a vectorized version that uses 3x `addpd` (packed double), just storing / reloading 128-bit vectors that partially overlap.  This will cause store-forwarding stalls, but out-of-order execution may be able to hide that.  It's just really weird that it branches at runtime on a calculation that will produce the same result every time, and never uses that loop.  Smells like a bug.

---

**If `glob[]` had been a static array**, you'd still have had a problem.  Because the compiler can't know that `v1/v2.data()` aren't pointing into that static array.

I thought if you accessed it through **`double *__restrict g = &glob[0];`**, there wouldn't have been a problem at all.  That will promise the compiler that `g[i] += ...` won't affect any values that you access through other pointers, like `v1[0]`.

In practice, that does *not* enable hoisting of `comb()` for gcc, clang, or ICC `-O3`.   But it *does* for MSVC.  (I've read that MSVC doesn't do type-based strict aliasing optimizations, but it's not reloading `glob.data()` inside the loop so it has somehow figured out that storing a double won't modify a pointer.  But MSVC does define the behaviour of `*(int*)my_float` for type-punning, unlike other C++ implementations.)

For testing, [I put this on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByHQGY8tZK1NYA1FtsBhAG6ZkRYg9sLQkAQTsHJxdMdy9mYmJmAE8gkPDee0dnNw9PIwJ0LCpuBFSwtIB6CtcTAFsYozwALxi0Wnz1AjS2/JrmzAB9AlcAOViAEVdOCQkPfXKwqprUetdffxIjV3V0bYTkozTTRo01vwmagpAQdYDc9DMAI3ZU23nQ44dgPeIL/PRrvFEikvA9TM9MKRbK93ksgQc9q06PliKZ/JhdlRmPlML8ELiYuhTDEiK4ANa0VAAd1ofRapFcj1Mw0IrjwWzwCUw7G8nW6yOG6zWnHc0l0PAkpAAtBLSBKtNJxnN%2Be1BedvLxReLuJLeDq5TqFUq3irekDtiKFfoxbKZfr5Yqjcqwj1hubmJqrVbZXrJQ6lY6TQtQktbiRXKT8iQkbVHg5mAQ8MjXKgqGcNsQtuH4UlDmF/tcw4FQU8XrZsK5gKxUI8ICNSBIdQBKZ3hRbVOoxuO0BNJ2hpDqJ5Bs2isByYNJgiGuNCxiBT9iuWoMhcxKgt8pitKuVzETAEcy02ruPSuKitp3BqoDAYJgjEPBMgiDAZQSkOMe0TBNjehbyoPBdmxIxMFjdgBnWCBfy9MIdx3KpV1cAAqG89xRPB/ErC4dAANirGstDEXRZjEY13jg1wlgLG4/DuEtwTLCtcO%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%2BR7k/bHR5EmIJJPAwAuJYfWpg4Nmh6CYNgOB4ARhHEKRZHkBRnc0AXVEfbXICZ1BzcTZEWalAB1NhWFcKUI9sRf/lY4BaFMAXOGkReZ8pKVTE3kD0C1swLDbpnWBZtmOb9jXs/4HCpRwkQZ371xpB1HVXAgXBCHDHYTgDIq61AdriUWnAmyuH5klPQEspY/lILLeW19Fbs3rvLFWasNZax1qQPW3MmZG1NvbK2uJyCUDIY7bwyBzbmwgpwQQAxOA4QGNnV%2B7tPa4m1hAX2scA4VwbqHFY4cCBR1YDHNW8d1BVmsNIzktF06YEzmrHOednzCKLmgtWpdy6V2rsI%2B8eB65WHFkzJujAWBJ3bkIUQkgZC9z7rIlAg9S4jygurCefZM5L14GfYWl8Fa32wTzFmHC361CMLQ4UghuCsN/v/AIkCQEW3Ib8OwvBoGwNUroBB%2BskH4mYFgYglAr4syVqQTBkpQnqxZng3WiCZZy0lGg2wyt771IIU0hW/i76x1wd0gpTNfCZj7CAEQQA%3D%3D%3D)

```
//__attribute__((noinline))
void assemble_vec()
{
     double *__restrict g = &glob[0];   // Helps MSVC, but not gcc/clang/ICC
    // std::vector<double> &g = glob;   // actually hurts ICC it seems?
    // #define g  glob                  // so use this as the alternative to __restrict
    for (size_t i=0; i<N-2; ++i)
    {
        g[i] += comb(v1[0],v2[0]);
        g[i+1] += comb(v1[1],v2[1]);
        g[i+2] += comb(v1[2],v2[2]);
    }  
}
```

We get this from MSVC outside the loop

```
    movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rcx]       # v2[0]
    movsd   xmm3, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
    movsd   xmm4, QWORD PTR [rcx+16]
    addsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rax]       # += v1[0]
    addsd   xmm3, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    addsd   xmm4, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
    mov     eax, 98                             ; 00000062H
```

Then we get an efficient-looking loop.

So this is a missed-optimization for gcc/clang/ICC.

Comment: "The same optimizations could have been done, because you've promised the compiler that g[i] += ... won't affect any values that you access through other pointers". Strangely, neither gcc or clang exploit this. They generate the same code, no matter of `__restrict` (I've checked this with gcc 8.2.0 and clang 8.0.0).

Comment: I accessed glob in assemble_vec() as you explained. It doesn't seem to change anything (clang 7.0 and gcc 8.2).

Comment: @geza: Weird, you're right.  MSVC is the only compiler that actually takes advantage of  `__restrict` to enable the optimzation exactly the way I described.  (I almost didn't bother trying MSVC, that was a surprise.)

Comment: @MFnx: yeah, geza already commented that.  Turns out only MSVC finds the optimization that `__restrict` allows here!  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

## GCC (and probably Clang) are optimizing out the Arrays, but not the Vectors

Your base assumption that arrays are necessarily slower than vectors is incorrect. Because vectors require their data to be stored in allocated memory (which with a default allocator uses dynamic memory), the values that need to be used have to be stored in heap memory and accessed repeatedly during the execution of this program. Conversely, the values used by the array can be optimized out entirely and simply directly referenced in the assembly of the program.

Below is what GCC spit out as assembly for the `assemble_vec` and `assemble_arr` functions once optimizations were turned on:

```
[-snip-]
//==============
//Vector Version
//==============
assemble_vec():
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR glob[rip]
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR v2[rip]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR v1[rip]
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
        lea     rsi, [rax+784]
.L23:
        movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rax, 8
        addsd   xmm0, xmm2
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax-8], xmm0
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+8]
        addsd   xmm0, xmm1
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx+16]
        addsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rdx+16]
        addsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax+8], xmm1
        cmp     rax, rsi
        jne     .L23
        ret

//=============
//Array Version
//=============
assemble_arr():
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR glob[rip]
        movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movsd   xmm3, QWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
        lea     rdx, [rax+784]
.L26:
        addsd   xmm1, xmm3
        addsd   xmm0, xmm2
        add     rax, 8
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax-8], xmm0
        movapd  xmm0, xmm1
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm1
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
        addsd   xmm1, xmm2
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax+8], xmm1
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L26
        ret
[-snip-]
```

There are several differences between these sections of code, but the critical difference is after the `.L23` and `.L26` labels respectively, where for the vector version, the numbers are being added together through less efficient opcodes, as compared to the array version, which is using (more) SSE instructions. The vector version also involves more memory lookups compared to the array version. These factors in combination with each other is going to result in code that executes faster for the `std::array` version of the code than it will for the `std::vector` version.

Comment: Nice answer! Clang did the array version about 67% faster, gcc 100%.

Comment: Clang with `-stdlib=libc++` (instead of the usual `libstdc++`) *can* optimize away alloc/free for `std::vector`, if you have libc++ installed (https://libcxx.llvm.org/).  I think this includes cases when the final result is unused and the loop over the array/vector can be optimized away, too.

Comment: But anyway, the asm you show here looks like the `vec` version didn't prove that `glob` and the source arrays didn't overlap, so it's actually reloading `v1[0]` and redoing the add repeatedly, in case the store to `glob[i]` changed it.

Comment: And as @geza commented on the question, yes the compiler is optimizing away `a1[]` and `a2[]`, and loading the sums from `.LC1[rip]`.  This is the key point.  The `array` version isn't using "more efficient opcodes", both of them are pure scalar.  (`movapd` is how you copy an xmm register, whether you're interested in the whole thing or just the scalar double or float at the bottom. 
 `movsd xmm,xmm` does a merge, with a dependency on the output register, so compilers would never use that except as a shuffle)

Comment: @PeterCordes This is very interesting! I confirmed what you stated by changing the comb function to m + c*f where c is a variable that changes for each iteration. The performance of both versions is now equal.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that you use too small storage size (six doubles), this allows the compiler, in the `std::array` case, to completely eliminate  in RAM storing by placing values in the registers. The compiler can store stack variables to registers if it more optimal. This decrease memory accesses by half (only writing to `glob` remains). In the case of a `std::vector`, the compiler cannot perform such an optimization since dynamic memory is used. Try to use significantly larger sizes for `a1, a2, v1, v2`